# Perl regex to match pair of strings

Tags: regex, perl, grep

Here is my regex link: https://www.regex101.com/r/jksOY7/1

I am getting matches with my regex. But the problem is output. I am getting six matches. If I use while loop, Then i am getting continue output.

But i need to relate as below using Perl.

```
[{
  match1=> 'GEL-111111111-22222',
  match2=> 'UP   Ej011.2223'
},
{
  match1=> 'FPL-222222222-33333',
  match2=> 'UP   Ek04112.2883'
},
{
  match1=> 'HGL-333333333-44444',
  match2=> 'UP   Eg04213.2323'
}]
```

The below Perl code is just returning continue output.

```
while($tunnel =~ /(?![\-]+)([A-Z]{3,5}-[0-9\-\_]+)|(UP\s+([A-Za-z0-9\/]+.[0-9]+))/g){
    print "\n";
    print Dumper $1;
    print "\n";
    print "\n";
    print Dumper $3;
    print "\n";
}
```

How can I get output as above?

Comment: To get the two capture groups in one match, you need describe the content between the two groups instead of using an alternation `|`. Also the third capture group (or the second, depending of what you want) and the lookahead are useless, remove them. Other thing, you need to escape the dot.

Comment: Not really a solution but kind of an optimization: https://www.regex101.com/r/jksOY7/2 - with a branch reset as well: https://www.regex101.com/r/jksOY7/3

Comment: Can you show the output  you want/expect?

Comment: I need output as mentioned in the JSON format. With the current regex, i am getting it as a continuous one.

Comment: Oh ... sorry, that's output? Is code supposed to print that exact stuff out? (Or do you mean to simply show what the matches should be?) But what input is being processed?  Also, what do you mean by "_returning continue output_"? I don't understand this at all.

Comment: Also as per @CasimiretHippolyte , I am separating regex group with "|" and i dont know how those strings with one regex.

Comment: @zdim I am sorry for that. The regex are matching the strings but what i use that with Perl (while loop), i could not able to form JSON string as mentioned. So it may be the problem with my regex or with the Perl code.

Comment: @Raja  Hang on. So the regex you show parses some strings (which you don't show), and you know that it's correct? OK. Now, do you want outout as shown under "_relate as below_"?  What you print in the `while` loop cannot possibly produce such output.  Also, you mention JSON -- do you want the result to be JSON?  If so, you need to do the following: use regex matches to form a data structure suitable for conversion to JSON using a module, say [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm). Then you convert it. I suggest that you edit the question and clarify these things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137700/discussion-between-raja-and-zdim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Perl is a little rusty.

Expanded regex

```
 (?s)
 ( [A-Z]{3,5} - [0-9_-]+ )     # (1)
 (?:
      (?! -------------- )
      . 
 )*?
 (                             # (2 start)
      UP \s+ 
      [A-Za-z0-9/]+ \. [0-9]+ 
 )                             # (2 end)
```

Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


$/ = undef;

my $teststring = <DATA>;

my @ary;

while ( $teststring =~ /(?s)([A-Z]{3,5}-[0-9_-]+)(?:(?!--------------).)*?(UP\s+[A-Za-z0-9\/]+\.[0-9]+)/g )
{
    my $href = {};
    $href->{'group1'} = $1;
    $href->{'group2'} = $2;
    push @ary, $href;
}

print Dumper \@ary;

__DATA__

Group      Name       FT   Description            FT       Description            DT
------------------------   -----------------------------   -----------------------------
GEL-111111111-22222
           IWRJWERODSF_WERONSDFELEO_23232
                      UP   Ej011.2223             DWD       56.67.22.234    1222332432
                                                                                    DWW
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FPL-222222222-33333
           WERWERDSFSD_PJRRINSDFKEW_10022
                      UP   Ek04112.2883           DWD     78.24.85.344    1232332432
                                                                                    DW
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HGL-333333333-44444
           SDFOWERNOWE_SDFONWERIODS_232323
                      UP   Eg04213.2323           DWD      Eg04213.2323             DWD
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'group1' => 'GEL-111111111-22222',
            'group2' => 'UP   Ej011.2223'
          },
          {
            'group1' => 'FPL-222222222-33333',
            'group2' => 'UP   Ek04112.2883'
          },
          {
            'group1' => 'HGL-333333333-44444',
            'group2' => 'UP   Eg04213.2323'
          }
        ];
```